# Type '"deb' is not known on line 1 in source list

Tags: command-line

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and especially to using terminal commands. I love the system and regret not having discovered it years ago.

In playing around with it and tweaking my system (Ubuntu 13.04) I have somehow lost control of my terminal function. When I attempt to run a command in the terminal I get an error msg.:

```
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Is there any way for me to regain control of the terminal and/or stop the "virtualbox error?"

Comment: Are you running the Raring Ringtail(Ubuntu 13.04) on a virtualbox?.  It is still in developing stage though.

Comment: I didn't install it in a virtual box, I did try to install the virtualbox program and that is what got it stuck. I was able to fix the problem by runnung the following:  gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

Comment: And deleting line 1.

Answer (score 10):

Run `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`, remove the `"` at the beginning of the first line, save and close. All done.

Comment: What about: *I have somehow lost control of my terminal function.*?