# ' "deb' file is not known

Tags: wine, dependencies, deb

I am a new linux user, and installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS ~3 days ago. (A.K.A, no clue what I'm doing)
When I was trying to install WineHQ using the code 'sudo apt-get install wine', it showed the following error:

E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

E: The list of sources could not be read.

I have tried to download multiple programs using sudo and they have all resulted in this error.
There's also an error notification at the top bar saying the same thing, but adding that 'This usually means the packages have unmet dependencies.'

Sidenote: the file type shows as "deb and not 'deb or .deb

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: After install, you made some typo or mistake when trying to change or edit your sources. You may have forgotten, bu the system remembers. Get into the habit of cleaning up mistakes before they cause problems like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type '"deb' is not known on line 1 in source list](https://askubuntu.com/q/264041/)